# How to do account activation through email using Djoser and React Native?

Tags: django, react-native, djoser, react-native-linking

I am currently doing the authentication for my React Native based application using Djoser in the backend. However, for account activation Djoser sends a link containing the uid and a token. I want this link to open a page on my app while I obtain the uid and token from the link. I need to send the uid and token in the link as the body in my activation request from my react native app.Please suggest how that can be done. Any help would be appreciable because I'm stuck on this particular part.

Comment: If you find any solution. Please share with me. I also get stuck in this issue

Answer (score 1):

I integrated djoser and reactjs. so it's  nearly similar like react native.It is may be usefull.

**IN your django settings.py:**

```
DJOSER = {
       ....

    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'user_activation/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL':True,
      .....
}
```

**Urls.js**

```
....
<Route path="/user_activation/:uid/:token" component={ActivateAccount} />
....
```

**ActivateAccount.js:**

```
const ActivateAccount = () => {

const { uid, token } = useParams();

const history = useHistory();

const activeClick = (e) => {
   
    Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/users/activation/', { uid: uid, token: token })
        .then(() => {
            history.push('/login')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            alert(err.response.data);
        })
};

return (
    <Fragment>
        <Button onClick={activeClick} color="primary">Activate Now</Button>
    </Fragment>
)
}

export default ActivateAccount;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, I'm relatively new to react native as well as Django(djoser). I'm confused about how the link received in the email will open in the app and how I'll be able to obtain the uid and token in the mobile app. Because when the url is clicked it directly opens in the browser.Please can you explain how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and found a blog article that shows how to make a link to your react-native mobile app: https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

This uses something called linking in react-native:

- [Linking with expo-cli](https://docs.expo.io/guides/linking/)
- [Linking with native code](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)

**More specifications:**

With djoser you can send an email to the user that provides an url to activate the user's account. This url you send should link to your frontend which will then call your api and activate the user. With the technique specified in the blog you will probably be able to do such a thing.